# Validating Admin in Angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, admin

I'm trying to implement a website so that after logging in with username "Admin@gmail.com" and password "Admin", the user will be logged in and redirected to the home page. However, if the user has given any values other than the specified ones, the website will throw an error.

How can I write a piece of code in angular 2 to do such a thing?

The following is my login.component.ts file:

```
    import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
import { Router }      from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../Services/auth.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {
  message: string;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {
    this.setMessage();
  }

  setMessage() {
    this.message = 'Logged ' + (this.authService.isLoggedIn ? 'in' : 'out');
  }

  login() {
    this.message = 'Trying to log in ...';

    this.authService.login().subscribe(() => {
      this.setMessage();
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
        // Get the redirect URL from our auth service
        // If no redirect has been set, use the default
        let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/home';

        // Redirect the user
        this.router.navigate([redirect]);
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.setMessage();
  }


}
```

And my login.component.html file is:

```
<h1>Please login to proceed</h1>
<br />
<br />
<form >
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="uname" style="display: inline-block">Username:* &emsp;</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input style="display: inline-block" id="uname" type="text" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd" style="display: inline-block">Password:* &emsp;</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input style="display: inline-block" type="password" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="color: red">* Required Fields</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <button  class="btn btn-info" (click)="login()" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn">Login</button>
               </p>
            </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Route Guard. It will solve your solution.

// src/app/auth/auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

// src/app/app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: I have already used auth guard to redirect me and everything works well, I just need to compare the input the user enters to "admin@gmail.com" and password "admin". How can I write that in login.component.html?

Comment: You can add the form validation. but you have to hard code your user name and password. But it is not recommended. You can also create db and store the values and integrate with angular to access that data.

Comment: can you please show me how I can write the command in which I compare the values the user entered to the ones stored in the db?